# flutter update variable Getx

Tags: flutter, view, controller, flutter-getx, imagepicker

i con create a function for get image with GetX
and  create a File variable (imageFile) for save image
but can not update imageFile when pass this in app view ,

```
class LineScreenController extends GetxController {
  File imageFile;
  getImages(file) async {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    File file  = File(pickedFile.path);
    print(imageFile);
    update();
  }
}
```

in view  passing  lineScreenController.imageFile tofuncion.

```
   Container(
            child: GetBuilder<LineScreenController>(
                init: LineScreenController(),
                builder: (value) {
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 4,
                        child: Center(
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              lineScreenController
                                  .getImages(lineScreenController.imageFile);
                            },
                            child: lineScreenController.imageFile != null
                                ? InkWell(
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      await lineScreenController.getImages(
                                          lineScreenController.imageFile);
                                    },
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundImage: FileImage(File(
                                         lineScreenController.imageFile.path)),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : CircleAvatar(
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      child: Text('celect Image'),
                                   Image.file(File(_imageFile!.path))
                                    ),
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),  
                }),
          ),
```

Comment: Where do you set the value for imageFile !!?

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the value for `imageFile`

Convert the following line

```
File file  = File(pickedFile.path);
```

to

```
imageFile  = File(pickedFile.path);
```